# Bootstrap Modal is stretching to full page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

my bootstrap modal is not showing correctly. it is stretched to full page. I'm using a html page. it seems that the modal isn't inline but I also think that my code is correct.

```
<!-- MODAL SECTION -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="model-dialog">
        <div class="model-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Subscribe to our Newsletter</h4>
            </div><!-- modal header -->

            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Simply enter your name and email! To receive our <em>Newsletter</em></p>
                <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="subscribe-name">Your First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subscribe-name" placeholder="Your first name">
                    </div><!-- form-group -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="subscribe-email">and your email</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subscribe-email" placeholder="and your email">
                    </div><!-- form-group -->
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Subscribe!">
                </form>

                <hr>

                <p><small>By providing your email you consent to receiving our newsletters. <br>No Spam. Just good stuff. We respect your privacy &amp; you may unsubscribe at any time.</small></p>
            </div><!-- modal body -->

        </div><!-- modal-content -->
    </div><!-- modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- modal -->
```

Comment: `model-dialog` & `model-content` are misspelled (and in the wrong order): it's _modal-*_. See [modals](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="model-dialog">
        <div class="model-content">
```

should be :

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
```

Comment: ohh my god :) So much code and i wasted hours to resolve the Problem. Thank you very very much. All is working now. Have a nice Day and Regards.